Follow up to - How to restore transactions after full backup
Short Summary:
I'm trying to retire a computer that runs SQL Server and move to a new one.  I want to do the following:

Backup a database on old machine and restore it on new machine, leaving the old machine in Production.
Allow developers to add/update Logins & User permissions and test against new machine.  This could take a couple of days.
Take a tail-log backup on old machine and shut it down.
Restore that tail-log backup on the new machine, bringing its data in-sync w/ the old Production, thus making the new machine Production.

I found this answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/329381/275453 but it is not quite the same scenario. That answer showed the following steps:
One option to minimize downtime is as follows:

Take a FULL backup of the database. Keep it online.

Restore WITH NORECOVERY onto the destination server.
a. Assuming that took a long time then you might want to do an intermediate step:
Take a LOG backup of the source DB.
b. Restore that also WITH NORECOVERY.

Finally, take the server out of public access and/or put the source DB into single-user mode, and do a tail-log backup. This will place it into RESTORING mode which means no queries can be run on it. The backup should be very fast, especially if you did the intermediate step.

Restore this onto the destination server using WITH RECOVERY to bring it online.

Redirect clients to the new server and you are back in business.


In my case, I'm not worried about minimizing downtime.  In fact I want to allow a couple of days between restoring the DB on the destination server and applying the tail of the transaction log.
Then, after a couple of days, I want to apply the tail of the transaction log from the Production server to the new server and shut down the original Production server.
I tried this:
I backed-up WarehouseDEV (Production) and restored it as WarehouseDEV_2 using SSMS.
Made some changes to a test table in WarehouseDEV
BACKUP LOG WarehouseDEV TO DISK = 'D:\Data\WarehouseDEV_TranLogBU.TRN' WITH CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR
RESTORE LOG WarehouseDEV_2 FROM DISK = 'D:\Data\WarehouseDEV_TranLogBU.TRN' WITH RECOVERY
The RESTORE command failed with following errors:
Msg 3117, Level 16, State 4, Line 17
The log or differential backup cannot be restored because no files are ready to rollforward.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.
Probably because when I restored WarehouseDEV_2 I did not use the NORECOVERY flag. I don't think I can leave the database in a NORECOVERY state for a couple of days while  developers access it (but I don' know).
Is this the correct technique to accomplish the mission? Can I leave the new destination server in the state after step 2 above and still let developers have access to it? (this seems like it would be problematic from a DB integrity point of view)
If that's not possible then what is the right way to do accomplish the mission?
I'm starting to consider a table-by-table data re-loading script scenario but that will be very labor intensive.  Hoping that there is a way to utilize the Transaction Log.


because when I restored WarehouseDEV_2 I did not use the NORECOVERY flag.

Correct, you need to use NORECOVERY to be able to apply log backups. Only the final RESTORE should have WITH RECOVERY to bring it online.

I don't think I can leave the database in a NORECOVERY state for a couple of days while developers access it.


I'm not worried about minimizing downtime. In fact I want to allow a couple of days between restoring the DB on the destination server and applying the tail of the transaction log. Unless perhaps you mean that

These two statements seem contradictory: either you want to go offline for two days while testing, or you do care and want a shorter offline time, which is why you'd use the process in my other answer you referenced. Whichever you do, all restores should be WITH NORECOVERY apart from the last restore.
The idea when I made that comment on your previous question was that you should test the whole process of restoring. Devs should not be messing with any of this process by making new changes. It's a simple matter of scripting out (using SSMS etc) all server-level logins, roles, permissions, certificates, CLR assemblies, SQL Agent jobs, and anything else you want to copy. Don't forget to script out reconnecting orphaned users to logins. You may also want to script out (or not probably, because they often aren't great) the old server settings. Then test the full restore process, barring the final tail-log, and check your applications can work with the new server. You shouldn't use this server as a production server at this point, it's literally just for testing.
Once you know it all works then you can proceed with the full process, which, now that you've scripted it out, should be very fast, it should take a matter of hours at the most.

Take a normal full and log backup
Scrap the test restore and WITH REPLACE over it.
Take the final tail-log backup (hopefully now a tiny size) which shuts down the production database, and restore that to the new server.
Change DNS settings or application connection strings, to redirect everyone to the new server.

The whole cutover time can therefore be reduced to a matter of minutes. But if you don't care about the cutover time and want to "Test in Production" then you can just do a normal full, log and tail backup immediately and bring it all online.
